# How does one run Dart VM in interpreter mode with JIT off?

Tags: dart, virtual-machine, jit

Is it possible to run Dart VM in a *100% interpreter mode* without any dynamic code generation (without JIT)? In other words is it possible to turn off native code generation at runtime?

If it is possible then "how easily" can it be done?

If Dart VM does not support this in a straightforward fashion, how much work is required for making this supported? I guess this is a question for people familiar with the internals of the VM.

I am thinking about using Dart VM in environments where runtime code generation is prohibited (e.g. iOS)

Answer (score 3):

The Dart VM doesn't have an interpreter, it generates machine code directly from the source code. This means you'd pretty much have to write an interpreter from scratch.

However you could use dart2js and a javascript interpreter.